# Oracle select date interval by its end from one date column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `Log` with `Doc` and `OperDate` columns and two indexes on each of them.
I want to select all rows by given date along with previous date partitioned by `Doc`

Something like

```
with 
Dates as (select trunc(sysdate) ate from dual),
  Log as (select 1 Doc, D.ate OperDate from dual, dates D union all
          select 1, D.ate-1 from dual, dates D union all
          select 1, D.ate-2 from dual, dates D union all
          select 2, D.ate from dual, dates D union all
          select 2, D.ate-3 from dual, dates D union all
          select 3, D.ate-4 from dual, dates D)
select A.Doc, A.OperDate, (select max(B.Operdate) from Log B where B.Doc = A.Doc and B.OperDate < A.OperDate) 
  from Log A
 where A.OperDate = trunc(sysdate) -- parameter
-- result = 2 rows
```

This will be two indexed accesses to a table and on the other hand if I use analytic functions I think I will lose access by index. Can this query be optimized?

Comment: correlated subqueries are fast, i would remove the max and choose LIMIT 1 instead

Comment: removing the max could change the results... using `LIMIT` or `ROWNUM` to get the first row assumes that Oracle will use a concatenated index (which OP doesn't yet have) in a descending order. This can be forced with an `INDEX_DESC` hint along with an `ORDER BY doc DESC, operdate DESC` to precisely match the index definition, but isn't a safe/reliable method since hints may not be honored in all cases.

Comment: Ayg, see my response to your comment to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not lose index access just because you use analytic functions. But, you'd lose access by removing the predicate on `operdate` in order to feed all the rows into that function, since you can't guess how far back the previous date is.

Assuming your data volume is such that index use is appropriate here, **create a composite (multi-column) index on `LOG(DOC,OPERDATE)`** to facilitate the subquery. Your existing index on `OPERDATE` by itself will be used by the main query block. Your index on `DOC` isn't useful, at least for this purpose. The composite index I'm suggesting would replace it.

However, if you only have a month and are asking for a day and the number of rows in a day is pretty high, or if you're on Exadata, you may be better off without using indexes and write it this way:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT /*+ parallel(8) */
               doc,
               operdate,
               LAG(operdate) OVER (PARTITION BY doc ORDER BY operdate) previous_operdate
          FROM log)
  WHERE operdate = TRUNC(sysdate)
```

Try it both ways and see which works best for you.

Comment: This query for some reason stops using the index on `operdate`. If I comment `lag` the index starts to be used. So it's not because of the nested query but because of the function

Comment: No, it's because there's no predicate on operdate within the inner query block. When you comment out the LAG Oracle is able to push the predicate in the outer query block into the inner one. If instead you had a predicate inside the inner query block that filtered on operdate, you could still use LAG and an index at the same time... but then you wouldn't get the results you want. That's what I was explaining in my opening sentence. But my response is primarily to create the 2-column index. The SQL you see is a second option for comparison of performance. Try the new index with your orig query

Comment: I was not trying to give you a LAG option that uses an index. I was giving you an index fix while using your current query, AND also another option which is LAG without an index. You have to compare the performance of the two to see which works best for you. Don't assume using an index is best.

Comment: I understand, thx. Of course index is the best :) But I won't be allowed to create indexes for no good reason

Comment: No, you don't know that index is the best. It may be, it may not be. There are a lot of factors involved here. The # of rows per day, the size of your table, whether your table is partitioned on the operdate column, whether this is Exadata, how wide the table is, whether you can use parallelism or not, etc.. etc.. there is never a "fastest" method in any and all circumstances. Try it both ways and see which works best. I suspect the index method will be better but only testing will prove that to be the case for sure.

Comment: Ask your DBA to drop the index on DOC and recreate it on two columns, in the order I specified: (DOC,OPERDATE). That *will* perform better than what you have now.